# tofixed(2) function apply to html class by name

Tags: javascript, html

The function is working correctly if simply var x (a digit)
but when I am trying to apply the same to html table class by name it is not working at all

```
<html>
       <body>
          <tr>
             <td class="sal">45.515420</td>
          </tr>
          <script>
             function myFunction() {
             
                var sal = document.getElementsByClassName("sal");
                for (i = 0; i < sal.length; i++) {
                 var currentValue = sal[i].innerHTML;
                var newvalue = (sal.toFixed(2));
                 sal[i].innerHTML = newValue
                
             }    
             }
             onload = myFunction()
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `HTMLCollection`s don’t have a `toFixed` method. Only numbers have those. `Number(currentValue)` is a number. `onload = myFunction()` doesn’t make sense; did you mean `onload = myFunction`? Use `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction);` or simply `myFunction();` instead (your `<script>` is already at the bottom of `<body>` — there’s no point in waiting for the DOM to finish loading).

Comment: which method i should use

Comment: don't even use that: put your script in a file and load it with `<script src="..." async defer></script>`, now your code will run only once the DOM's done, no `onload` on `domcontenloaded` required anymore. The need for writing JS code to wait for the right every wasn't been a thing for a surprising number of years now.

Comment: I guess what you're trying to do is to get `currentValue.toFixed(2)` as @SebastianSimon is saying there is no `toFixed` on an `HTMLCollection`

Comment: @GijsBeijer `currentValue` is a string, not a number.

Comment: well I am not hard core programmer.
just finding a java function to make html class to show the number format in 00.00

Comment: some more notes: use `querySelectorAll`, which gives an array-like that lets you use `forEach`, and don't look at `.innerHTML` but look at `.textContent`, which gives the clue as to what you're going to work with: all HTML text is literally text. If you know it's a number, you'll have to first turn it into one with `parseFloat()`. And when you're updating an element's text, use `.textContent = ...`, don't use `.innerHTML` unless you _actually_ need to get or set raw HTML code.

Comment: @Avi Well, it looks like all you need is `document.querySelectorAll(".sal").forEach((element) => element.textContent = Number(element.textContent).toFixed(2))`. Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: @SebastianSimon You're right, but I still think that's what he's trying to do although then he should also cast the content as a float using `parseFloat()`. I'll edit the comment

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you can `<tr>` elements just floating around without at least a `<table>` container, and even a `tbody`.

Comment: @Andy `<tbody>`s get introduced into a table automatically, but yes, without a `<table>`, the resulting HTML is indeed just `45.515420`; the element with `class="sal"` doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to use `document.getElementsByClassName` on `td` elements, you need to wrap your tr and td element inside `table` tag.

Second, `toFixed()` is a method for number and you need to convert the string to a number using `Number()` before you use `toFixed()`.

```js
var sal = document.getElementsByClassName("sal");
for (i = 0; i < sal.length; i++) {
  var currentValue = sal[i].innerHTML;
  var newValue = Number(currentValue).toFixed(2);
  sal[i].innerHTML = newValue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="sal">45.515420</td>
          <td class="sal">49.515420</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The provided code needs some changes, I'll try to address them:

- Convert `currentValue` to number because `toFixed` is part of a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

  ```js
  var currentValue = Number(sal[i].innerHTML);
  ```
- `onload = myFunction()`, we can just call the function to run it on load

  ```js
  myFunction();
  ```
- Wrapped `<td class='sal'>45.515420</td>` in a `<table>` to make the HTML valid

  ```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='sal'>45.515420</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

Applying those fixes gives:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var sal = document.getElementsByClassName("sal");
    for (i = 0; i < sal.length; i++) {
      var currentValue = Number(sal[i].innerHTML);
      sal[i].innerHTML = currentValue.toFixed(2);
    }    
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='sal'>45.515420</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good and clear answer while explaining on other errors in code

Comment: Mm, care to explain why you've changed the accepted answer Avi?

Answer (score 1):

Along with all the other good advice, here's version that uses more modern JS practices.

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
const sals = document.querySelectorAll('.sal');

sals.forEach(sal => {
  const number = Number.parseFloat(sal.textContent);
  sal.textContent = number.toFixed(2)
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="sal">45.515420</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```